# SSAS cube from a flat table

Tags: ssas, cube, flat, denormalized

I'm trying to figure it if one can build an SSAS cube quickly for prototyping from just one huge and wide table without doing any ETL and custom SQL. Is it even possible?

What we are trying to do, we have a bunch of these tables for different subject areas which were denormalized and a lot of efforts were put to create them and test them. We need a quick way to access this data now and run analytical queries but before we spend time on ETL/dimensional design, we wanted to build a quick cube.

Please do not suggest PowerPivot or any other in-memory tools - these tables are really big and we have very limited RAM at our disposal,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. Simply use the same table for creating both dimensions and cubes (measure groups). It's not ideal to do it like this for production, but you should be fine for prototyping.

Another alternative I always use in situations like this, create SQL views on top of the wide table to mimic the dimension and facts (dimensional model). And use views in the data source view. If you've time you can spend on creating the views, this is the best method. Because at the end of the prototype you know the model and functionality is working, and you just need to create physical data warehouse and ETL when you're ready to implement in production.